# Unexpected performance issue

Tags: node.js, performance, router

I've recently written a nodejs package [अनुमार्गाक (Anumargak)](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/anumargak) which is used for HTTP routing. I'm facing a weird performance issue.

It has a method `on` to register a route and `find` to find registered route.

```
var anumargak = Anumargak();
anumargak.on("GET",'/some/url',fn);
anumargak.find("GET",'/some/url');
```

When a user calls `on` method it first calls `find` method to check if the route is already registered otherwise saves the route information in 2d array. When the user calls `find` method, it just look for an entry in 2d array.

```
Anumargak.prototype.on = function(method,url,fn){
    if(this.find(method,url)){
      this.count --;//count of unique registered routes.
    }
    this.count +=1;
    this._on(method,url,fn);//_on method has actual logic of saving route information
}

Anumargak.prototype.find = function(method,url){
    var result = this.staticRoutes[method][url];
    if(result) return result.fn;
    else{
        //handles dynamic routes
    }
    return this.defaultFn;
}
```

`find` method has no dependency on `on` method. But when I call find method from `on` method, performance of find method decreases to half. I'm calling `on` method only once and testing the performance of `find` method. What can be the possible reason?

I'm using node v9.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what was the issue with performance. But calling `this.find()` was incorrect. Because `this.find` accepts actual URL whereas registered URLs can have regex or param detail.

Hence I've rewritten the code to fix the issue which solved performance as well.